# Whole TD as hyperlink in scalable table

Tags: css, html, html-table

I need to accomplish that my whole TD is a hyperlink. 
Other solutions I found on the internet won't seem to work. Like the one shown beneath.
Therefore I want to know if you guys could help me out.

I think the problem might be the fact that this is about a scalable table.
If so, is there another way to accomplish my goal?

```
<div class="block">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://example.com">
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    Test
                </div>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="google.com">Google</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="google.com">Google</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="google.com">Google</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #008700;
}

.block table {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.block table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #008200;
}

.block table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #205527;
}

.block table tr {

}

.block table tr td {
    float: left;
}

.block table tr td a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "height:100%" to :

```
.block table tr td a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Didn't see that one coming.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMYe5/2/)

Firstly remove `float: left;` from `.block table tr td`

Then add `height:100%;` to `.block table tr td a`

Answer (score 0):

you need add in block table tr td a height: 100%;